# Execute a script in phantomjs interactive (REPL) mode

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have a file that runs and prints output to the screen when I run it in phantomjs non-interactive mode

```
$ phantomjs file.js
<stuff printed to screen>
```

In phantonjs interactive (REPL) mode is there a way to run a js file, something like `run('file.js')`.  I want to open up phantomjs as a pipe and send it multiple files to execute before closing the pipe to save on startup overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like REPL mode is borked and and an overhaul is underway:

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11180