# PhantomJS says repl-input:1 in global code when trying to run a script from interactive mode

Tags: ssh, terminal, phantomjs

I am really lost with phantomjs on using it in the terminal. I want to go to my website under a proxy and perform p.js but it keeps spitting out errors that I don't understand. It wont even go there without the proxy..

```
phantomjs> --proxy=190.40123.36:8080 http://example.com/req.php
Unexpected token '='

phantomjs://repl-input:1 in global code
phantomjs> --proxy=190.40123.36:8080 /home/engine/public_html/p.js http://example.com/req.php
Unexpected token '='

phantomjs://repl-input:1 in global code
phantomjs> --proxy 190.40123.36:8080 /home/engine/public_html/p.js http://example.com/req.php
Unexpected number '190.40123'

phantomjs://repl-input:1 in global code
phantomjs> /home/engine/public_html/p.js http://example.com/req.php
Expected an identifier but found 'http' instead

phantomjs://repl-input:1 in global code
phantomjs> /home/engine/public_html/p.js http://example.com/req.php
```

what is repl-input:1 in global code?

I know it hasn't got to my site even on the last command because in req.php I am getting the php $_SERVER object and fwrite'ing to test.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 /bin/phantomjs --proxy=socks://190.40.123.36:8080  /home/engine/public_html/req.js http://example.com/req.php
```

must be socks5 i think

Status success!

Answer (score 2):

PhantomJS has two commandline modes. One where you run a script and one where you have an interactive prompt.

What you are doing is running the interactive prompt and trying to specify commandline options and the script to run.

You can either run the interactive prompt with the proxy settings enabled and try to interactively create the page:

```
$ phantomjs --proxy=ip:port
phantomjs> var page = require('webpage').create();
undefined
phantomjs> ...
```

I always found that this doesn't work as expected, because [REPL is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17708657/1816580).

The other way is to write a script and run it with your options in a non-interactive manner:

```
$ phantomjs --proxy=ip:port script.js url
```

The errors you were getting is because this<sup>1</sup> is not valid JavaScript.

<sup>1</sup> `--proxy=190.40.123.36:8080 /home/engine/public_html/p.js http://example.com/req.php`

Comment: the interactive propt says Unexpected number '190.40123' and the other way says Expected an identifier but found 'proxy' instead

Comment: I just copied the option from your question. I don't know why there is a dot missing in your IP. There also must be an `=` sign between `--proxy` and IP.

Comment: /bin/phantomjs --proxy=190.40.123.36:8080 /home/engine/public_html/p.js http://example.com/req.php running the command now all I see is the word hello. what the hell is that? I didn't write hello anywhere!

Comment: lol, sorry I was going mad. --proxy=socks://ip:port is the fix!!