# PhantomJs does not return any status when making an http request in console

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I downloaded PhantomJS, launched the exe and typed in console

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://net.tutsplus.com', function(s){console.log(s);})
```

I didn't see status "success" returned in console and no error either. Why?

I tried using hello.js it prints "success" but it does not in interactive mode, is this normal?

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you have? Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. the latest version as I donwloaded it today. I followed tut from here http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-javascript-with-phantomjs--net-28243. Is it deprecated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use interactive mode to open pages. Something prevents PhantomJS from opening pages, so the callback is never called. If you wait a little and try to access `page.content` it still shows the about:blank content. [This is because REPL mode is broken.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17708657/1816580)

---

**Previous answer** in case this is used as a script and not in interactive mode:

I believe this is a flush problem. Add a second `console.log()` to see if the first one appears.

Also, it is always a good idea to close the script at which point the output *will* be flushed:

```
page.open('http://net.tutsplus.com', function(s){
    console.log(s);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

I could reproduce this issue on Raspbian with PhantomJS 2.0.1-dev *once*. All other invocations had no problem anymore.

Comment: OK I tried using hello.js it prints success' but in console it does not, is this normal ?

Comment: Oh, you mean in interactive mode. That never worked, at least for me.

Comment: This is a huge bug it should be fixed.